# Why slaughtering of animals is not considered as cruel as opposed to what vegetarians think?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, animals, dhabihah

Vegetarians think that killing animal for our own comfort is cruel because we can live even without eating meat then why to kill animals. They are also living creatures as we and killing them is equally painful for them as for us. 
I need answer in context when someone does not believe in Quran/Prophet etc.

Comment: Who said we can live without eating meat?

Comment: I live in Germany and I witnessed a lot many people who are vegetarians and don't consume meat at all and apparently have no health issues.

Comment: I see. I am not saying a person couldn't survive without meat or that the way we consume meat today is healthy for us or the environment. But the consequences if EVERYBODY stop eating meat is something else.

Comment: @Kilise Can you prove the consequences?

Comment: It's not possible to prove anything yet, too much data is needed and there are so many factors involved, in both cases. That's why one can't say we should ONLY eat vegetarian food and one can't say we should ONLY eat meat.  I'd argue that the world's population should be semi-vegetarians and eat less than we do today (and of course eat less meat than we do). This is a good article: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/earth/environment/12052711/Lettuce-worse-than-bacon-for-the-environment-scientists-claim.html

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/food-and-drink/news/healthy-foods-that-are-ruining-the-environment/ forgot to add this article too..

Comment: did you read my comments and the articles? Do you got any feedback?

Answer (score 3):

Then "killing" plants also does not seem right to me as they're living things too like us (keeping aside if they feel pain or not). We wouldn't have survived till now if we were not to eat them killing mercilessly.

Things are perfectly defined as what are good and what are bad in Islam.

We check the condition of the animals before slaughtering (healthy, fit, young etc.) because we're told to do so.

Don't you think deceiving a cow while getting milk is wrong? Might be, but we're not obliged to not deceive it, so we have it. Don't you think killing plants is wrong? We're not obliged to not kill them, so we have them.

**We're not obliged to not kill animals, so we have them.**

> *O ye people! **Eat of what is on earth, Lawful and good**; and do not follow the footsteps of the evil one, for he is to you an avowed enemy. (Qur'an [2:168](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=2&verse=168))*

Besides, having meat is not a compulsion (AFAIK). Just because they're good for our health (and tasty). Causing them pain intentionally should not be our intention.

*Allah knows the best.*

Comment: Although you gave one or two good reasons but you quoted Quran and I was asking for an answer for someone who does not believe in Quran!

Comment: Leave it then. The rest should probably suffice.